# iOS - Share image using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, ios8-share-extension

I'm reading whatsapp [documentation](https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/23559013) and I wonder if there is a basic example of Share Extension implementation using UIActivityViewController as is mentioned in docs.
I've tried instantiate an UIActivityViewController object but I can't find an uti property.

I've found examples using UIDocumentInteractionController but I don't want an option list. I want share an image only with whatsapp.

Answer (score 0):

You just create an instance of `UIActivityViewController` and pass the `UIImage` object you want to share:

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
```

Or alternatively, you can wrap the data you want to share with `NSItemProvider` and choose the proper UTI (`typeIdentifier` parameter):

```
let item = NSItemProvider(item: image.pngData(), typeIdentifier: "public.png")
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: nil)
```